# Javascript audio not playing

Tags: javascript, html, audio

I get a headache trying to understand why my script is not playing the sounds like i want to.
I have a quite simple HTML/Javascript animation with several sounds into it, executed on user's interaction (swipe, click, validate...).

Here is the url if you want to test and see the complete source :
http://artcode.fr/apps/bioprojet/simulation/index.html

The issues are at step 4 & 5 : 
Step 4, clicking on the red button makes it disappear, execute an "injection sound", plays "validate sound" and then goes to step 5 where there should be a clock sound executed each second during the countdown to 10.

This regular behavior is ok in desktop browser (Safari/Chrome), but when launched in Safari mobile ou Chrome mobile, the sounds on step 4 are not always played (sometimes even inverted), and the clock sound on step 5 is never played.

I tried a lot of things to make it work, with no success, as :

- "currenTime" and "pause()"
- "onended" event, but doesn't seem to work on mobile
- different sounds, to see if the issue came from this (answer is no)
- inverted places

Here is the part of the code where the mess is :

```
if(e==4){       
    $("#voir_etape_3").addClass("voir_etape_on");               
    $("#bouchon_rouge").click(function(){ 
        clic.play();                            
        $("#anim_clic").animate({ top: "110px" }, { duration:50, complete: function(){                                                                  
            var pauseclic = setInterval(function(){
                clearInterval(pauseclic);                                   
                valide.play();                                      
                $(".etape").hide();
                $("#etape_5").show();                                   
                actions(5);
            },2000);
        }});                            
    }); 
}
if(e==5){
    $("#voir_etape_4").addClass("voir_etape_on");                       
    var t=0;
    var decompte = setInterval(function(){ 
        t++;
        if (t<=10){ 
            tic.play();                                                                                         
            $("#decompte").text(t); 
            if (t==10){ $("#decompte").addClass("decompte_on"); }                           
        } else{ 
            $("#decompte").addClass("decompte_on");                                                 
            if (t==11){
                clearInterval(decompte);
                tictactic.pause();
                //tictactic.currentTime = 0;                                
                valide.play();
                $(".etape").hide();
                $("#etape_6").show();                                   
                actions(6); 
            }
        }
    }, 1000);
}
```

Sounds are defined at the beginning of my javascript script :

```
var valide = new Audio('./graph/valide.mp3');
var tic = new Audio('./graph/tictac.mp3');
var tictactic = new Audio('./graph/tictactic.mp3');
var clic = new Audio('./graph/clic.mp3');
```

Comment: this might help you http://jsfiddle.net/shrinivas93/1gt1Lzr6/5/

Comment: turn your speakers up. it plays on my machine

Comment: On which mobile device did you hear the sound ?